# How to remove an entry from messaging menu in C

Tags: messaging-menu

I wrote a simple C program to create a entry in messaging menu.code is shown below.

```
#include <messaging-menu.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    MessagingMenuApp *mmp=messaging_menu_app_new("gnome-terminal.desktop");
    messaging_menu_app_register(mmp);
    return 0;
}
```

And it works as expected.

Then I add a line 'messaging_menu_app_unregister(mmp);' to remove the entry, but failed.

```
#include <messaging-menu.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    MessagingMenuApp *mmp=messaging_menu_app_new("gnome-terminal.desktop");
    messaging_menu_app_register(mmp);
    messaging_menu_app_unregister(mmp);
    return 0;
}
```

The API document says messaging_menu_app_unregister() 'Completely removes the app from the Messaging Menu.' But it doesn't work in my machine, Ubuntu 13.10.

I want to remove the entry in C or Shell .any help?

Sorry for my English and thanks in advance.

Comment: How is this related to Ubuntu?

Comment: Of course it's related to Ubuntu. I'm using Ubuntu and the messaging menu is owned by Ubuntu Unity, isn't it?

Comment: This is about programming friend you can get answers in stackoverflow

Comment: Ubuntu related programming questions are definitely on-topic and are encouraged.  This question has been reopened.